Issue with Printing Web Pages on Android OS Using Google Chrome
Description: I'm trying to print a web page from Google Chrome on my Android device, but I'm encountering issues. When I tap the menu button and select "Print," nothing happens, and no error message is displayed.
Steps to Reproduce:

Open Google Chrome on an Android device. Navigate to the web page
you want to print. Tap the menu button (three dots) and select
"Print." Describe what happens next and what the expected outcome
is.

import { PrintReport } from "@/views/app/Anbar/Input/print.js";

then using computed property, when I receive data from store execute it:
const print_data = computed(() => {
  if (store.state.tradeModule.anbar_print) {
    if (store.state.tradeModule.anbar_print.master) {
      if (store.state.tradeModule.anbar_print.master[0]) {
        PrintReport(store.state.tradeModule.anbar_print);
      }
    }
  }
  return store.state.tradeModule.anbar_print;
});

An this is code that receive data from store and create a html page and using js add a blank page in browser and show form ready for prit:
import PersianDate        from "persian-date";
import { PrintCss }       from "@/composables/PrintReport.js";
import { setNumber }      from "@/components/base/mixins.js";
import { htmlContent }    from "@/views/app/Anbar/Input/print_html.js";


export const PrintReport = (data) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const jalal = new PersianDate();
    const url = new URL(location.origin + '/printable.html');
    const win = window.open(url);
    const title = "نمایش و چاپ ورودی انبار"

    let matn = data.master[0].Matn
    if(data.master[0].Matn===null || data.master[0].Matn===undefined || data.master[0].Matn.length===0){
        matn = data.master[0].TypeHamlName
    } else {
        matn = data.master[0].TypeHamlName + ' | ' + data.master[0].Matn
    }

    let htmlFileText = String(htmlContent)
    .replace(/@PreFactor.Company/g, data.master[0].TypeName)
    .replace(/@PreFactor.PrintHeader/g, data.master[0].EventName)
    .replace(/@PeopleName/g, data.master[0].PeopleUserName)
    .replace(/@value_PrintDate/g, jalal.rangeName().weekdays[jalal.State.persianAstro.weekday-1]+':'+jalal.year()+'/'+jalal.month()+'/'+jalal.date() +" ("+date.getHours()+':'+date.getMinutes()+")")
    .replace(/@ErsaliAz/g, data.master[0].PeopleName)
    .replace(/@Daryafi/g, data.master[0].AnbarListName)
    .replace(/@DateAnbar/g, data.master[0].DateAnbar)
    .replace(/@Serial/g, data.master[0].Id)
    .replace(/@value_matn_master/g, matn)
    .replace(/@report_rows/g, print_data(data.list))
    

    win.document.write(`
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>${title}</title>
        <style>${PrintCss}</style>
      </head>
      <body style="direction:rtl;">
        <form name="form1" id="form1">
            ${htmlFileText}
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
}
const print_data = (mores) => {
    let result = ""
    mores.forEach((dr, index) => {
        result +=`<tr style="height: 22px;">
            <td style="height: 20px; width: 30px; left: 626px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; text-align: start; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; ">
                <strong>${index+1}</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 20px; width: 207px; left: 406px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; text-align: start; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; ">
                <strong>${dr.KalaName}</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 20px; width: 60px; left: 333px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; text-align: start; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; ">
                <strong>${setNumber(dr.inPut)}</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 20px; width: 120px; left: 200px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; text-align: start; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; ">
                <strong>${dr.StateName}</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 20px; width: 120px; left: 67px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; text-align: start; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; ">
                <strong>${dr.TypePackageName }</strong>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 20px; width: 50px; left: 4px; position: absolute; padding: 0px 5px; text-align: start; border-radius: 5px; border: 1px solid black; overflow: hidden; font-size:12px;">
                <strong>${setNumber(dr.PackageCount)}</strong>
            </td>
        </tr>`
        if (dr.Matn && dr.Matn.length>0){
            result +=`<tr>
            <td col-span="5" style="height:18px; position: relative; padding: 0px 5px; text-align: start; overflow: hidden; ">
                <p>${dr.Matn}</p>
            </td>
            </tr>`
        }
    })
    return result
}

A new tab is opened, only html data is present and print is done by browser, in desktop, on pc without any problem.
** htmlContent is a pure html string only that format final work.
Problem: Using Android OS and Google Chrome, I open the same page and touch the print icon. A new page opens, and then I try to print using normal print apps like NokoPrint and PrinterShare, but it is not possible.
Point: I can print the parent page, but not the popup page. The difference I noticed is that the parent page has a valid URL, but the print page is with "about:blank" URL. As I have found out, apps try to download the page by their internal browser and not get content from the current page, so they are unable to print.
Even when I tried to load the website inside NokoPrint, the popup page is ignored or blocked.
Questions:
Have you encountered this situation before?
Do you have any experience with this issue?
How do you send out prints on Android + Chrome? Can you help me?
